# Can I prevent programs to open port in windows firewall?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-firewall

When Windows Firewall is activated, newly installed programs open incoming ports. Can this be prevented somehow?

Comment: UAC prevents this by default. When you enter your administrator password or click "Yes" in the UAC prompt, you are effectively saying "Yes, program, you can make changes to my registry, firewall, settings and files".

Comment: Clarification: Can I prevent it in any case? So you have to add these firewall exceptions manually?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? As far as I know, each program you install will have logic built into the installation/setup process to open the firewall ports programmatically using commands and such opening what's needed for the application to work. I suspect if you install elevated, then that elevated credential would have access to open the firewall up. An idea that may be worth testing would be to completely disable the Windows Firewall (I have a post or two explaining this simple process) before the install, run the install, re-enable the FW, and then check to confirm, etc.

Comment: For example here.... as I wrote about [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1335258/windows-10-private-firewall-blocks-all-internet-traffic/1337194#1337194) you can run `netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off`, do your install, and then run `netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state on` after the install.